# Horizontal alignment - subfigure

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, horizontal

I am trying to make the second image (top right) horizontally aligned with the first one and I don't succeed. Any suggestions?
I already looked for similar questions and I can't solve it with the usual suggestions.
Thank you.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{subfigure}[a]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Imagenes/PC.jpg}
\caption{Fosfatifilcolina (PC)}
\label{fig:PC}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Imagenes/PA.jpg}
\caption{Fosfatidiletanolamina (PA)}
\label{fig:PA}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Imagenes/PS.jpg}
\caption{Fosfatidilserina (PS)}
\label{fig:PS}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[d]{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Imagenes/PI.jpg}
\caption{Fosfatidilinositol (PI)}
\label{fig:PI}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Principales fosfolípidos según grupo funcional}
\label{FFL}
\end{figure}
```

[image: alineacionhorizontal]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please make your ecample code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also clarify the desired alignment. Do you want two images to be top or bottom aligned or vertically centered?

Comment: It seems as if you tried to use the optional argument of the `subfigure` environment to "number"  the subfigures (see for example the `a` in  `\begin{subfigure}[a]{0.48\textwidth}`) . This argument actually only accepts `b` for **b**ottom, `c` for **c**enter and `t` for **t**op. Try with these or leave them out entirely to get vertically centered images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first optional argument to `\begin{subfigure}` in square brackets `[]` is not the subfigure tag (a, b, c, d), but its vertical alignment: `t` for top, `c` for center and `b`for bottom. In this case, you can leave it out:

```
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
```

and use

```
\end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
```

after your first and third subfigures to make sure the horizontal spacing is the same for both rows. Make sure to replace `example-image-*` with your actual filenames in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Fosfatifilcolina (PC)}
        \label{fig:PC}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Fosfatidiletanolamina (PA)}
        \label{fig:PA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Fosfatidilserina (PS)}
        \label{fig:PS}
    \end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Fosfatidilinositol (PI)}
        \label{fig:PI}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Principales fosfol\'ipidos seg\'un grupo funcional}
    \label{FFL}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]